# Is it possible to give non base64 string as input in AWS cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

This maybe an amateur doubt but I am stuck and unable to figure out a workaround for this problem. I need to input general string characters (with line breaks) which are not supported by base64 text format. I know that we can upload text files onto S3 buckets, but is there a way to use that text file and parse it as input for my Cloudformation template using the file's S3 url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, but the roundabout way I have done this in the past is to use an AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource resource type to execute an AWS::Lambda::Function resource. The Lambda can return outputs, which other resources in your template can then reference via Fn::GetAtt. You can see an example of how to implement this here: [AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html)